# Implement complement of rule in decision table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a query to make decisions based on multiple criteria using a decision table.

Suppose here I need to know a result (Yes or No) depending on attributes a person has as shown in Table.

```
DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_decision`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_decision` (
  id_rule       INT NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  rule_name     VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  minVal        INT NOT NULL,
  maxVal        INT NOT NULL,    
  decision      CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `uc_decision` UNIQUE (`id_rule`)           
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Insert into `tbl_decision` VALUES
(1, 'WEIGHT'      , 60  ,100 ,'Y'),
(2, 'HEIGHT'      , 0   ,170 ,'Y'),
(3, 'Special rate', 10  ,30  ,'Y'),
(4, 'Consumption' , 0   ,3300,'N');
```

Here is the table I am comparing to:

```
DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_guy`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_guy` (
  id_guy    INT NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  guy_name     VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
  weight        INT NOT NULL,
  height        INT NOT NULL,    
  rate          INT NOT NULL,    
  consumption   INT NOT NULL,    
  CONSTRAINT `uc_guy` UNIQUE (`id_guy`)           
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


Insert into `tbl_guy` VALUES
(1, 'John'      , 200,220,10,1000),
(2, 'Mary'      , 100,160,11,5100),
(3, 'Diana'     , 80 ,155,19,4000),
(4, 'Ruthanne'  , 82 ,165, 5,2000);
```

The decision is determined by the following query.

```
SELECT *  FROM 
(
 SELECT id_guy,decision,
CASE WHEN rule_name = 'WEIGHT'       THEN tbl_guy.weight
     WHEN rule_name = 'HEIGHT'       THEN tbl_guy.height
     WHEN rule_name = 'Special rate' THEN tbl_guy.rate
     WHEN rule_name = 'Consumption'  THEN tbl_guy.consumption
END AS testQnty, rule_name, minVal, maxVal
FROM tbl_guy CROSS JOIN tbl_decision
) t 
WHERE minVal <= testQnty AND testQnty < maxVal 
ORDER BY id_guy;
```

I am using min and max values to know if decision is Yes, However I do not know how to define a opposite rule. For instance I define:

(3, 'Special rate', 10  ,30  ,'Y')

to be yes if guy value on field rate is between 10 and 30

but on field consumption if It is between 0 and 3300 decision is NO

(4, 'Consumption' , 0   ,3300,'N');

I know you can always make opposite rules using complement so
if  `0 <= x <= 3300`  would become  `x < 0 AND x > 3300`
but how to enable that on query?

[Here is my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40606/9)

[other](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40606/15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `decision` seems to embody two concepts.  One is the direction of the rule (is it "between" or "not between") and the other is whether the rule passed.  To clarify things, the following keeps all the rules along with a new variable to determine if the rule passed:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (case when decision = 'Y' and minVal <= testQnty AND testQnty < maxVal
             then 'Passed'
             when decision = 'N' and not (minVal <= testQnty AND testQnty < maxVal)
             then 'Passed'
             else 'Not Passed'
        end) as RuleResult
FROM (SELECT id_guy, decision,
             (CASE WHEN rule_name = 'WEIGHT'       THEN tbl_guy.weight
                   WHEN rule_name = 'HEIGHT'       THEN tbl_guy.height
                   WHEN rule_name = 'Special rate' THEN tbl_guy.rate
                   WHEN rule_name = 'Consumption'  THEN tbl_guy.consumption
              END) AS testQnty, rule_name, minVal, maxVal
      FROM tbl_guy CROSS JOIN tbl_decision
     ) t 
ORDER BY id_guy;
```

If you want only rules that pass:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT id_guy, decision,
             (CASE WHEN rule_name = 'WEIGHT'       THEN tbl_guy.weight
                   WHEN rule_name = 'HEIGHT'       THEN tbl_guy.height
                   WHEN rule_name = 'Special rate' THEN tbl_guy.rate
                   WHEN rule_name = 'Consumption'  THEN tbl_guy.consumption
              END) AS testQnty, rule_name, minVal, maxVal
      FROM tbl_guy CROSS JOIN tbl_decision
     ) t
where (decision = 'Y' and minVal <= testQnty AND testQnty < maxVal) or
      (decision = 'N' and not (minVal <= testQnty AND testQnty < maxVal))
ORDER BY id_guy;
```